# ISPConfig - Let's Encrypt not available after upgrade

Tags: apache, https, debian, lets-encrypt, ispconfig

I just upgraded from ISPConfig 3.0 to 3.1.2 on Debian 7.
According to the Changelog, Let's Encrypt is now supported.

However, I don't see any Let's Encrypt specific options. I can create an SSL certificate from the SSL tab of a Website, but accessing the domain using https:// results in the following error in Chrome:

This site can’t provide a secure connection.

Is Let's Encrypt only available for new (clean) installations?
 - or will the proper options emerge if I install e.g. CertBot or some other package?

It seems CertBot has a plugin for Apache that automates everything, but I'm worried ISPConfig and CertBot will conflict when both trying to control configuration files.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Jimmy

Comment: I realized that HowToForge would be the ideal place to ask. Here is the response I received from Till Brehm:

"1) You have to install certbot and just certbot, no certbot apache plugin. and do not create ssl certs with certbot at install time, when it asks for that, choose cancel.

2) then login to ispconfig, go to the website settings amd emable the checkbox labeled "Letsencrypt" which is on the first tab of the site settings. The SSL tab is not used for letsencrypt."

https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/ispconfig-lets-encrypt-not-available-after-upgrade.75540/#post-355688

Answer (score 0):

I realized that HowToForge would be the ideal place to ask. Here is the response I received from Till Brehm:

"1) You have to install certbot and just certbot, no certbot apache plugin. and do not create ssl certs with certbot at install time, when it asks for that, choose cancel.

2) then login to ispconfig, go to the website settings amd emable the checkbox labeled "Letsencrypt" which is on the first tab of the site settings. The SSL tab is not used for letsencrypt."

It worked just the way he said.

https://www.howtoforge.com/community/threads/ispconfig-lets-encrypt-not-available-after-upgrade.75540/#post-355688